# Draw power grid network topology

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I am creating an application in C# in which I need to create power grid network topology. The expected output is: http://goo.gl/M9UJP

Is there any package in C# using which I can create required picture dynamically?

Comment: Not terribly likely. Looks like you'd better warm up those `OnPaint()` event handling skillz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this manually by using the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

If you are looking for a third party solution, then you need to search for yourself, as this would primarily be opinion-based and not a good fit for this site.

Comment: I guess you're right. I will close this question by marking your answer correct.

Comment: cant you draw the image?(just asking cuz i dont know what the end result needs to be exactly).

Comment: I want the image to be changed dynamically. Like the text labels shown in the image will change dynamically.